# Expressive power of lexer + parser

Tags: formal-languages, parsing

Most modern compilers split their syntax analysis into
a lexical phase that is followed by a parsing phase.
The lexical phase is given by a regular expression, while parsing
is guided by a context-free grammar.

What class of languages can be recognised this way? 
Context-free languages, or can we get into context-sensitive 
languages?

Comment: Lexer adds nothing to expressiveness, it only separate for efficiency.

Comment: I think there is more than efficiency at stakes, the is also
modularity and perspicuity of the compiler architecture with respect
to the concepts that structure the programming language. Hence it is
also, and possibly much more, an issue of maintainability and
reusability of the sofware components. But greater specialization of
the components is certainly also a source of efficiency.

Comment: One advantage of separating the lexer and parser is that it lets us restrict the number of lookahead tokens in the parser to a small number. It wouldnt be as viable to do such restrictions with lookahead characters instead of lookahead tokens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the question, this recognizes only context-free languages.

Lexical analysis is actually a GSM mapping, i.e. a finite state
transduction. Since CF languages are a [full Abstract Family of Languages (full AFL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_family_of_languages), they are closed under
inverse GSM mapping. Hence, if the sequences of lexemes parsed by the second phase belong to a  context-free language, the original texts as a sequence of characters also belong to a
context-free language.  This 2 levels organization does not change the CF
characters of syntax, assuming the second level is indeed context-free.

One point is worth noting, though it is a minor technical issue. To
have this CF character of the second phase, it is necessary that identifiers be replaced
by a finite set of standard categories represented each by a unique
symbol. The same is true for literals such as strings or numbers. The
point is that many languages do not in principle put any limit on the
size of identifiers, or some literals, so that there is in principle an infinite number
of them. But the context free grammar of the second phase must have a
finite alphabet, like any CF grammar.  Hence the lexical elements
returned by the first phase cannot actually distinguish all
identifiers, or all literals, for the second phase.

However the information is kept by other means for the more semantical
phases of the compiling process.

It is true that any given program does have a finite number of
identifiers and literals, but the point is that we are considering the language of all possible programs.

Another point is of course that texts of compiler accepted programs do
not form a context free language as other constraints (such as
declarations of identifiers) are imposed on programs, in parallel to
the strictly syntaxic parsing process.

But, ignoring those more "semantics" constraints, some parsers also
use a variety of parsing "tricks", such as prioritization of reduction
rules to avoid ambiguities or non-determinism. As long as this is done
with a finite memory and a pushdown stack that is used only within a
fixed finite distance from its top, this does not get the syntax out
of the context-free realm. However, what extra parsing rules may exist
for the parser also have to be known to the users of the language,
thus making the understanding of the syntax more complex to users, and
giving more ground for misunderstanding. TANSTAAFL. Supposing this is
used to reduce ambiguity, it could then happen that the user will read
his program one way, while the parser reads it another way.

My own preference is for general CF parsers, that will detect
ambiguity (which is, of course, decidable for a given string of an
ambiguous language), and reject it as a programming error. But that is
much a matter of taste in design.

Including the lexical phase into the context-free syntax may possibly
make those extra rules more complex, as reasonning can no longer
isolate lexical issues fron CF syntactic ones. It can also make the
automaton underlysing the parser more complex, or call for more extra
rules. Typically, if parsing the CF part of the syntax requires a
lookahead that may include an identifier, the look-ahead becomes
unbounded when identifiers are not reduced to one symbol by a lexical
phase. Much depends also on the chosen parser generation technology.

Though there are some [scannerless parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scannerless_parsing) used, I would think this applies more to languages with specific lexical and syntactic characteristics. But I am no expert on this, and the wikipedia page seems a bit weak on the general presentation side.

Finally, another interesting point, close to the initial question is
error recovery. It is used by compilers so as to be able to catch many
errors at each run, and was important when compiling was done in batch
mode, rather than interactively. Many syntactic error recovery
techniques are based on a formal model of finite state generation of
errors, such as missing or extra symbol, or local garbling of the strings
(this is also true for natural language processing). This can also be
modeled by a GSM. Hence, ignoring again semantical aspects, the larger
language of *programs with syntactic errors* accepted by a parser with
error correction is also context-free.

*There is more in the comments, but how long should an answer be?*

Comment: Thanks. Has this result been proven somewhere that I can point my students to?

Comment: Regarding AFLs and closure properties, it is in many textbooks on
formal language theory. See for example Hopcroft and Ullman, which is
given as reference in the pointer to wikipedia I gave with AFL (click
on AFL, I realize it is not too visible). The second part, about
finite representation of some infinite sets, I do not recall seeing it
anywhere, that explicitly. People do that routinely without thinking
twice, I guess. It is more a formal point that I developed because of
the way the question was being asked.

Comment: Thanks. Another question: are there known bounds on the blowup of the CFG when we move from lexer/parser to a scannerless parser? IIRC the people who work on scannerless parsers add gadgets like reject rules to CFGs to keep their grammars manageable.

Comment: The point about finite representation is interesting. This works in practise because the parser simply ignores the content of the tokens that carry information like `tokenIdent( ... )` or `tokenNum(...)`. This content is only used later in type-checking and code generation.

Comment: @MartinBerger To be honest, I do not know of scannerless parsers for compilers. Do
they give motivation? In theory, cascading automata in this way can be
formalized by a cross-products of the states, which in the worse case
leads to a number of states that is the product of the number of
states of each automaton. In grammar size terms, you can have pretty
bad behavior if the CF grammar is not in binary form, at least with
respect to non-terminal (meaning at most 2 for the right-hand side of
each rule), as there are combinatory issues with the lexer states.

Comment: @MartinBerger Blow-up is mild, just the CFG + the sum of all regular expressions resp. grammars used for specifying the lexer. They integrate naturally. I don't think you'll find an answer in theory for the separation; ease of implementation and error handling are probably the main drivers, though I'm speculating here.

Comment: @Raphael I gave the theoretical blowup of integrating the cascading of two
automata (pushdown and finite state). Parsing a string can be seen as
cascading a finite state machine accepting just that string with a
PDA. It is in general cubic in the size of the string. So I doubt
theory says that blowup is mild, unless you make more precise what you
mean.- - But worst case analysis says nothing of grammars that are
designed from the start to do scannerless parsing, or of the specifics
of programming languages. If the combinatorics were as bad as I think
they can be, people would probably give up.

Comment: @babou You are thinking of the intersection construction? Well, I was thinking in terms of grammar and build the PDA of the resulting one. I don't have a proof relating its size to the automaton resulting from the original grammar, but I think the addition of PDA+FA sizes applies, too. (It seems as if this issue might be worth being explored in a dedicated question?)

Comment: @Raphael I had that cross-product scheme in mind (I avoid calling it
intersection, since it is also used for other purposes) because the
initial question asked did put me in that frame of mind. Actually, you
are right that the lexical features are very localized on specific non
terminals in the CF syntactic structure, thus causing little
interference with the CF structure. Hence things add instead of
multiplying. When you commented, I was about to note that people would
not use it if combinatorics was that bad. Actually, there is no
combinatorics, or very little, with PL lexical structure.

Comment: @Raphael Things may not be too bad on the grammar side, because they
just change some terminals of the CF part into non-terminals with
associated rules describing their lexical structure. So this is quite
simple. However, this may have pretty bad effects on the syntax, as
parser may become higly non-deterministic, especially for a
complex language requiring LR parsing. Of course, the non-determinism
can be handled with look-ahead, but this entails an explosion of the
number of states. Things are highly dependent on the class of the CF
kernel of the syntax.

Comment: @babou The paper *Scannerless Generalized-LR Parsing* by E. Visser explains the concept. Incidentally, the Wikipedia page on [scannerless parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scannerless_parsing) claims that "when parsed at the character level, most popular programming languages are no longer strictly context-free".

Comment: @Raphael A lexer is not just the sum of regular expressions, because if you simply add them, you get lexing ambiguity, e.g. if IDENT = [a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]* and KEYWORDS = "if" + ... then IDENT + KEYWORDS is ambiguous. Lexers use longest-match and rule priority (e.g. KEYWORDS first) to disambiguate. Does replicating that on the CFG level not lead to additional blowup?

Comment: @MartinBerger I'd assume that you can "hack" these rules into the PDA at the same cost as in the FA; afaik they don't appear in the grammar per se. Interesting, I think I underestimated the issues one might run into. :)

Comment: @MartinBerger Keywords are a small problem for identifiers, but not
worse than what is already in the lexer. Of course I looked at the
wikipedia page. But there is not much there that is substantiated, and
I have learned to be wary. So the sentence you quote would require at
least an example of what they have in mind. This looks much like
advertising Visser's work, which is the only reference, with a very
specific kind of parser. I will give it a look, but it may take more
than a day. GLR is not always as magic as believed. And scannerless
most likely does not always make sense.

Comment: @babou I agree that the Wikipedia page is weak. I have no experience with scannerless parsers. The question of the expressiveness of lexer/parser arose during a compilers course I was teaching last year. I want to give my students the right explanation.

Comment: @MartinBerger Mixing the lexical and CF phases may lose the determinism of
the language when a needed look-ahead becomes unbounded because of
it. This is related to the so called
[LR-Regular](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000073800509)
parsers, which do the very opposite of scannerless parsing, by
introducing a finite-state pass to make the pushdown pass
deterministic. In this sense, mixing the lexical part with the CF part may
actually weaken the parsability of the language, or limit the class
of practical CF-structures, or have an efficiency cost with GLR parsing.

Comment: @MartinBerger It does take a bit of time to get the various relevant ideas back together. This should be in the wikipedia article on scannerless parsing, but is not.