# Why separate lexing and parsing?

Tags: compilers, parsers

It's possible to parse a document using a single pass from a state machine. What is the benefit of having two passes, ie. having a lexer to convert text to tokens, and having a parser to test production rules on those tokens? Why not have a single pass that applies production rules directly to the text?

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/128888/are-separate-parsing-and-lexing-passes-good-practice-with-parser-combinators

Comment: This has already been discussed on CS,stackexchange, with many very technical comments in an answer to **[Expressive power of lexer + parser](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28858)**. But there may be room there for further answers.

Comment: I wonder if pipeline-style parallelism (albeit highly imbalanced stages) might be a side advantage. Both instruction and data cache behavior might also be interesting. How much (if at all) such would reduce compile time would depend on the specific hardware.

Comment: One fairly obvious (at least to me) reason is that you can then use the scanner tool separately.  In practice, I frequently use flex to scan input, but seldom need the full power of yacc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have to separate them. People combine them into [scannerless parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scannerless_parsing).

The key disadvantage of scannerless parsers appears to be that the resulting grammars are rather complicated -- more complicated than the corresponding combination of a regular expression doing lexing and a context-free grammar doing parsing on the token-stream. In particular, grammars for scannerless parsing tend towards ambiguity. It's easier to remove ambiguity for grammars working on a token-stream.

A pragmatic benefit of using a dedicated upfront lexing phase is that you don't couple the subsequent parser with lexical detail. This is useful during early programming language development, when the lexical and syntactic details are still changing frequently.

Comment: Having one pass instead of two passes involves closure properties.  If
you consider that lexers are transducers belonging to a formal family
$T$, that can be combined with parsers belonging to a formal family
$P$, you must wonder whether composing them stays in the same family
$P$, or requires a more complex formal family $P_T$, thus requiring
different algorithmics, and possibly more difficult tuning of syntax.
Parsing technology often relies on specialized families (such as LR or
LL variants) that may not have the right closure properties.

Comment: @babou Yes that is correct. I don't know any formal results of the form regular-expression composed with LL(k) goes out of LL(k), or similar. Moreover, lexing is usually not done with regular languages, but with something more powerful, namely regular languages extended with longest-match and keyword-first priorities. I'm not sure what exact language class that is and what its closure properties are.

Comment: If your look-ahead involves reading an identifier, the composition will require unbounded look-ahead, since there is (in principle) no bound on the length of identifiers.

Comment: @babou I'm not sure. If the longest keyword is 17 characters long, then any string that is longer must be an identifier, or lexically invalid.

Comment: But you identifier, or possibly a string, number or other literal, is a sequence more than 17 individual symbols, that may stand before the token you actually need. That is a big look-ahead, unbounded. You may end up with a non-deterministic language.

Comment: @babou I'm not sure I understand what you mean. All I wanted to say is that I don't know what the closure properties of the languages we use for lexing and parsing are when we separate those two, indeed I'm not sure exactly what the languages for pure lexing are, since they use priorities. This does not seem to be discussed in compilers or formal languages books.

Comment: Take the following grammar fragment: $\{X\to BAb; X\to CAc; B\to d;
C\to d\}$. Now you can choose the rule for $A$ as reading a single
token $A\to t$, or as reading all individual characters of that token
$A\to a\mid aA$. In the first case you can do the reduction of $d$ to $B$ or
$C$ with a small lookahead, and in the other case you need unbounded
look-ahead, to decide on how it should be parsed. But I agree that the informal character of that technology is an issue ... and I still doubt there is any good reason for it, other than technical ideology.

Comment: I think it would be nice for a modern compiler textbook to have a unified formal treatment that covers lexing with priorities, incremental lexing, the relationship with lexing and parsing etc.